# When UIButton is selected a white box appears over text label

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, if-statement, button

i have a button that when selected, a white box appears over the title text of the button. I dont want this white box to appear. See images.
[button state unselected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMa8K.jpg)
[button state selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmWE9.jpg)

If i remove the if statement and have the button so it can only be selected but not deselected, on selection, this white box doesn't appear. The code controlling this is below...

```
@IBAction func backButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        if let button = sender as? UIButton {
            if button.isSelected {
                createWorkoutButton.isEnabled = false
                backButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral
                backButtonPressed = false
                backButton.isSelected = false
            } else {
                createWorkoutButton.isEnabled = true
                backButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral
                backButtonPressed = true
                backButton.isSelected = true
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: are u trying to show an image when button is selected?

Comment: no, just change the background colour and the button state

Comment: Just check if you have the `.tintColor` of button as `.white` in storyboard. If yes, set it to `.clear` colour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found a solution. Add this line of code -

```
 button.tintColor = .clear
```

Now -

```
@IBAction func backButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        if let button = sender as? UIButton {
            if button.isSelected {
                createWorkoutButton.isEnabled = false
                backButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral
                backButtonPressed = false
                backButton.isSelected = false
                button.tintColor = .clear // Add this line of code
            } else {
                createWorkoutButton.isEnabled = true
                backButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral
                backButtonPressed = true
                backButton.isSelected = true
                button.tintColor = .clear
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In story board use button type custom. [image]